# How can I print all ListItems from a SharePoint Online List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

We just moved from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint Online. I want to retrieve the contents of a list, but the code below no longer works for SharePoint Online:

```
# Connect to Sharepoint Lists web service
$uri = "https://sharepoint2007site.com/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $uri –Credential $sharepoint_credential

# Set service url to SA portal
$service.url = "https://sharepoint2007site.com/teams/SysAdmin/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"

# Pull contents of server list
$listname = 'Listing'
$list = $service.GetListItems($listname, $null, $null, $null, 2500, $null, $null)
```

What is the SPO way of retrieving ListItems from a specified list?

Comment: Cross-site Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699338/how-to-get-items-from-a-sharepoint-online-list-using-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to retrieve list items has changed. Please refer below code to get list items from SharePoint. To run this Open the SharePoint online powershell:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

$siteURL = ""  //insert your site url 
$userId = ""   //insert your user name, like abc@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
$pwd = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString  
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userId, $pwd)  
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)  
$ctx.credentials = $creds  
try{  
    $lists = $ctx.web.Lists  
    $list = $lists.GetByTitle("TestList")  //change to your custom list
    $listItems = $list.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())  
    $ctx.load($listItems)  

    $ctx.executeQuery()  
    foreach($listItem in $listItems)  
    {  
        Write-Host "ID - " $listItem["ID"] "Title - " $listItem["Title"]  
    }  
}  
catch{  
    write-host "$($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red  
}
```

Comment: I downloaded CSOM to get the dlls and ran the code.  Returns this: Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Comment: did you enter site url and user name ?

Comment: Figured it out...minor typo on my part

Comment: NB - the folder path for the specified DLLs maybe in `[...]\16` instead of `[...]\15` these days as new PowerShell/CSOM versions have come out. At least, I was able to run this code and I have the DLLs in a version \16\ folder, but nothing in the \15\ folder.